# How to query values from XML without nodes?

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I have a XML like this:

```
<User LoginName="yes" Signature="A" MobilePhone="yes" />
```

and I use the following query:

```
SELECT field.value('/User[@LoginName=1][1]','varchar(max)') 
FROM table
```

I expect the output for LoginName to be "yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to get your expected result:

```
SELECT R.V.value('@LoginName[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS LoginValue
FROM   TestTable AS T
OUTER APPLY T.data.nodes('User[1]') as R(V)
```

Sample execution with some data:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (data XML);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (data) VALUES
('<User LoginName="yes" Signature="A" MobilePhone="yes" />
<User LoginName="no" Signature="B" MobilePhone="NA" />');

SELECT R.V.value('@LoginName[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS LoginValue
FROM   @TestTable AS T
OUTER APPLY T.data.nodes('User[1]') as R(V)
```

it will result as

```
LoginValue
----------
yes
```

Please find the [**working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ff0877613ee00e617cac07decdcf365)